# Summation of a series: if $s=\sum_{i=1}^\infty aix^i$, then $s=\frac{a}{1-x}+xs$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How is it possible that this equality holds?
$$s=\sum_{i=1}^\infty aix^i=\frac{a}{1-x}+xs$$
I do not know where does this come from.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply $s$ by $x$, you obtain

\begin{align}xs &= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty aix^{i+1}\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty a[(i+1) - 1]x^{i+1}\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty a(i+1)x^{i+1} - \sum_{i = 1}^\infty ax^{i+1}\\
& = s - a - \frac{ax}{1 - x}\\
& = s - \frac{a}{1 - x}.\end{align}

Therefore

$$s = \frac{a}{1 - x} + xs.$$

Comment: I think that you did some confusion with index i

Comment: @DavideF. those were typos. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

The condition $|x| < 1$ should be satisfied. Then:

$$s = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}aix^i = a \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{2}} = \frac{a}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$\implies (1-x)s = \frac{a}{1 - x} \implies s - sx = \frac{a}{1 - x} \implies s = \frac{a}{1 - x} + sx$$